# How to make <img> and <div> align in one row

Tags: html, css

I want to show profile picture and name in topbar, just like SO. But the image and text are still in two rows.
HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="" alt="" width="24" height="24" class="picture">
</div>

<div>
    <span>name</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
span {
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
}
img {
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
}
div {
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Added:**
I'm new to HTML and CSS. I thought making element attribute dispaly be inline-block could make them align in one row.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align images and div horizontal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985574/align-images-and-div-horizontal)

Comment: I tried in Chrome. And even [Align images and div horizontal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985574/align-images-and-div-horizontal) is still in multiple rows. @rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inline-block property does not support in some browsers.
[Please see here.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block)

In that case, you use only float property.
CSS

```
span {
    float: left;
}
img {
    float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="" alt="" width="24" height="24" class="picture">
    <span>name</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **CSS Flexbox**. This will also help you making your content vertically centered with only one CSS rule. Like:

```
/* Wrapper div of name & image */
.holder {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Responsible for aligning the content in the center vertically */
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.holder {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.name {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/24x24" alt="" width="24" height="24" class="picture">
  <span class="name">Name</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Star_Man It has issues with old versions IE. That's it! Its now works on every modern browser.

Comment: @Hel This will also help you vertically centering the content. I your case I think this is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```css
span {
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
  margin-left:5px;
}
img {
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="" alt="" width="24" height="24" class="picture">
</div>

<div>
    <span>name</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the divs set widths and then it will be inline. So if you give them 50% each then they will both appear in the same row.